# Selenium IDE - How to switch back to main content from an iframe

Tags: selenium, ide

Ok. I have selected my iframe and done my operation, now i want to switch back to main content and select a button. What is the Selenium IDE command to switch out of the iframe and back to the entire page content

Comment: I found the answer.. Command=SelectWindow and Target=null

Comment: Hi ziaprog; if you've worked out the solution yourself, then the best thing to do is to post it here as an answer to your own question, and accept it. That way your question won't keep showing up in the Unanswered list.