# What is the Selenium IDE equivalent for driver.switchTo.defaultContent?

Tags: iframe, selenium-ide

With the new Selenium IDE, I cannot find the way to switch out of an iframe back to the default content of the parent page. Selenium IDE script cannot find a button after being in an iframe.

The steps before failure include switching to iframe:index=2 and wait for an element visible in the iframe. When it tries to find the button on the main content, it fails to find the element.

Have tried the following to switch back to default content:

- Command='select frame'; Target=''
- Command='select frame'; Target='index=0'
- Command='select frame'; Target='index=1'
- Command='select frame'; Target='relative=parent'
- Command='select frame'; Target='relative=top'
- Command='select window'; Target='' (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564095/selenium-ide-how-to-switch-back-to-main-content-from-an-iframe))
- Command='select window'; Target='relative=parent'
- Command='select window'; Target='relative=top'

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a question of 3 years ago but to switch to the default content in Selenium IDE you must use the command:

```
select frame
```

with the target:

```
relative=top
```